# Where should I see the result of plotting a chart through SSH?

Tags: ssh, systemd, services, systemd-timer, plotting

I have created a systemd service like following code on my CentOS remote server that runs a Jupyter app named `scraping-cdn-plot-gavahi-aati.ipynb` that plots some charts. This is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ipynb Script Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ipython /root/scraping-cdn-plot-gavahi-aati.ipynb
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I  can run the service successfully and see this result when I start the service on the server:

```
● ipynb-script.service - Ipynb Script Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ipynb-script.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-18 11:56:04 +0430; 3s ago
 Main PID: 22796 (ipython)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ipynb-script.service
           └─22796 /root/anaconda3/bin/python /usr/bin/ipython /root/scraping-cdn-plot-gavahi-aati.ipynb

May 18 11:56:04 boiga.server1.more.com systemd[1]: Started Ipynb Script Service.
```

But I don't know where should I see the plotted result?

EDIT-Note: I can connect to the server through SSH and run the above Jupyter script using this address `http://localhost:8000/notebooks/scraping-cdn-plot-gavahi-aati.ipynb`(I use PUTTY on Windows 10 to do it). But what I am looking for is a way to connect a local installed application on my Windows like Spyder3 to connect to the remote server and see the plotting results.

Comment: If the server has a GUI program for plotting, you could log in with `ssh -X` (or corresponding tool in your local computer) and start that plotting program. Otherwise I think you must download the data file for example with `sftp' or Filezilla, and then you can use local tools for plotting.

Comment: @sudodus: What if is it a web scraping program that reads data online on the server and I like to plot the result and see it on my client?

Comment: You have a Windows client. I don't know what tools you have on Windows. But if there is a web interface, maybe you can use your web browser for that purpose (instead of putty).

Comment: @sudodus: I use PUTTY for SSH connection, and chrome for web interface.

Comment: According to [this link](https://activedirectorypro.com/ssh-clients-for-windows/) MobaXterm can do 'ssh -X', but we don't know yet, if there is a suitable GUI program for plotting that way in the server. -- The easy solution might be that you can create a file with putty, and view that file with chrome, or as I suggested in the first comment, to download the file and view it locally.